# Python multiprocess terminate other subprocesses inside chunked function

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a very slow and random function here.

I want the first result of foo() only.

```py
from random import randint
def foo(i): # Generating random number in a very slow way
    y = randint(1,1000000)
    while y != randint(1,1000000):
        pass
    return y
```

I want to increase the speed, so I have created few processes, 
but It slows me down and gives me unwanted result.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool(processes = 8) as pool:
    result = pool.map(foo, [i for i in range(8)])
# A lot of time passed
>>> result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

So, is it anyway to terminate other subprocesses inside chunked function and return the result just like this?

```py
from random import randint
def foo(i): # Generating random number in a very slow way
    y = randint(1,1000000)
    while True:
        x = randint(1,1000000)
        if x == y:
            pool.terminateAllOtherSubprocesses()
            return y
```

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool(processes = 8) as pool:
    result = pool.barFunc(foo, [i for i in range(8)])
# Less than a second passed
>>> result
[42]
```

Comment: What are you trying to solve in here?

Comment: @abstractpaper In fact, I am trying to get an URL using a lot of unreliable proxies.

Answer (score 0):

From python docs: [Exchanging objects between processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)